# How to ensure RNG entropy pool is "secure and full" for generating passwords with passlib?

Tags: python, passwords, entropy, passlib

When looking at using Python's passlib module, the documentation[1] comes with a warning for generating passwords which reads..

> Warning: Before using these routines, make sure your system’s RNG
>   entropy pool is secure and full. Also make sure that genword() or
>   genphrase() is called with a sufficiently high entropy parameter the
>   intended purpose of the password.

However it makes no mention of how this is achieved. In practice my understanding is that the entropy pool would fill gradually, usually through keyboard/mouse input but how is this achieved for a headless server for example, and how do you ensure it is secure/full before you call the genword/genphrase functions?

[1] https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/lib/passlib.pwd.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Linux: cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail

3590

The upper limit is 4096, anything close to this is OK

Below 200 is not good.

See: https://blog.cloudflare.com/ensuring-randomness-with-linuxs-random-number-generator/